# Black screen after uninstalling lightdm

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

i use 14.04 and have uninstalled Lighdm, because it runned jackd uppon starting the computer. Now when i start it goes into a black terminal, and i have no access anymore to the normal GUI display. how can i restore this? plz help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer…

Login into your terminal and install `lightdm` again:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

or maybe with `--reinstall`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

For the completeness

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and check the entry in `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`, it should be

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Restart or start `lightdm` with

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: i did it but it doesnt work. What did you mean by the way with login into terminal , did you mean the black one which looks like a X-windoes terminal? And if i try to install it again now i get: "lightdm is already the newest version"

Comment: Does it work when you run `sudo service lightdm restart`?

Comment: @amir therefore the 2nd command

Comment: @the_Seppi yes it works, but if i do a restart it goes again into the black terminal. it also goes to the normal GUI Login if i type in the terminal: sudo  start lightdm. How can i restore it so that it starts again normally without going first into the black terminal?

Comment: @A.B. yes it has functioned obviously, so i have lightdm again, but it doesnt start automathically

Comment: Have you tried the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: and check the entry in `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`, it should be `/usr/sbin/lightdm`

Comment: @A.B. the entry at X11 default-display-manager is /usr/sbin/lightdm. But it doesnt go yet stright in the normal desktop, i shoud run sudo start lightdm from the black terminal. The problem i actually had with lightdm was that it has prevented some programms from starting (pd-extended), as i looked in the top processes running, i saw jackd has been started by the USER lightdm, so i couldnt kill the process. thats why i tried to uninstall lighdm. do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Kill which process? `jackd` or `lightdm`

Comment: You have an user `lightdm`?

Comment: kill jackd. Yes i have a user lightdm!

Comment: Why the exclamation mark? Kill the service with `sudo service ... stop` or with `sudo pkill jackd` or with the process id `sudo kill pid`

Comment: You delete no user where you delete a program with the same name.

Comment: yes, it workes when i kill jackd with sudo. but it still run jackd upon each startup. How can one reconfigure it so that the jackd doesnt run automatically? Thankyou